# Difference between two techniques recycling list row views in Android

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I know the approach about recycling rows in list for the performance. What I see usually is the kind of technique that use `static` class and tags (`viewHolder`)

for example:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if ( convertView == null )
    {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.id.row, null);  
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txt1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.txt1 );
        holder.txt2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.txt2 );
        holder.txt3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.txt3 );
// setting more images,images
        convertView.setTag (holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag ();
    }

    holder.txt1.setText( data.get( position ).txt1 );
    holder.txt2.setText( data.get( position ).txt2 );
    holder.txt3.setText( data.get( position ).txt3 );

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder{
    TextView txt1;
    TextView txt2;
    TextView txt3;
}
```

but in some code I saw more simple approach that doesn't use `static` class and tags, it just check if the view is recycled if yes it uses it if not it create it.

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                if(convertView == null){
                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.history_row, null);
                }
        LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row);

      TextView txt1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
                    txt1.setText(data.getTxt1());
     TextView txt2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
                    txt2.setText(data.getTxt2());
     TextView txt3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
                    txt3.setText(data.getTxt3());

    }
```

What the different between them, and what is more better to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findViewById()` is an expensive call. One should avoid using it. In the first approach, `findViewById()` is called for all the newly created views and not for any convertView. In second approach, `findViewById()` is called for all the views. The first approach is undoubtedly better to use.